# I want to add '%' units to the values in my column

Tags: oracle, plsql

Data in Actual_results column: 6
Desired output: 6%

Procedure:

```
BEGIN

    SELECT CYTOTOXICITY_PF,
        CYTOTOXICITY_PER
    INTO bio_test,
        B_ACTUAL_RESULT
    FROM src_material
    WHERE study_id    =V_ITEM_ID(i)
    AND NEW_MAT_NUMBER=V_NEW_MAT_NUMBER(I);

    b_test3:='CYTOTOXICITY';

EXCEPTION

WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN

    INSERT
    INTO TCE_DATA_ISSUES VALUES
        (
            V_ITEM_ID(i),
            'CYTOTOXICITY',
            V_NEW_MAT_NUMBER(I),
            TRANS_NAME,
            'TOO MANY ROWS'
        );

    bio_test       :='';
    B_ACTUAL_RESULT:='';

END;

ELSE
    bio_test       :=F_GET_TEST_VALUE(V_ITEM_ID(i),b_test3,V_NEW_MAT_NUMBER(I));
    B_ACTUAL_RESULT:='';

END IF;
BEGIN

    INSERT
    INTO tce_test_result_form
        (
            UNQ_NUM,
            MIG_STATUS,
            ITEM_ID,
            REV_ID,
            FORM_NAME,
            CREATION_DATE,
            B4_TEST_NAME,
            B4_ACTUAL_RESULT,
            B4_PASS_FAIL,
            B4_EXTRACTION_TEMPERATURE
        )
        VALUES
        (
            V_UNQ_NUM,
            'CREATE',
            V_ITEM_ID(i),
            'A',
            CASE b_test3
                WHEN 'HEMOLYSIS_PF'
                THEN V_ITEM_ID(i)
                    ||'/A'
                    ||'_Hemocompatibility - In Vitro Hemolysis Assay Indirect'
                ELSE V_ITEM_ID(i)
                    ||'/A'
                    ||'_'
                    ||b_test3
            END,
            V_CREATION_DATE(i),
            CASE b_test3
                WHEN 'HEMOLYSIS_PF'
                THEN 'Hemocompatibility - In Vitro Hemolysis Assay Indirect'
                ELSE B_TEST3
            END,
            NVL(B_ACTUAL_RESULT,'N/A'),
            CASE
                WHEN BIO_TEST IN('P','P')
                THEN 'PASS'
                WHEN BIO_TEST IN('f','F')
                THEN 'FAIL'
                ELSE 'NOT REQUIRED'
            END,
            B_EXTRACT_TEMPERATURE
        );
```

How do I add '%' to ACTUAL_RESULTS?

Can I do `NVL(V_ACTUAL_RESULT || '%', 'N/A')` ?

(Because I was asked to update N/A if there's no value in ACTUAL RESULT)

Comment: You should not store the unit  in the same filed as the value

Comment: You'd be better off adding a 'Unit' field next to your value field, something like ` "%" as Unit, `. That way you can still do numeric operations on your value field

Answer (score 0):

Use decode to differentiate between N/A and other result

```
decode(V_ACTUAL_RESULT, 'N/A', 'N/A', V_ACTUAL_RESULT || '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do (if declared column datatype of V_ACTUAL_RESULT is compatible with CHAR)

```
NVL2(V_ACTUAL_RESULT, V_ACTUAL_RESULT || '%', 'N/A');
```